# how to render a component in reactjs without changing the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For Eg,
I have a blog web application which fetches the blog posts and displays as kind of thumbnails, upon clicking it, it takes us to the blog by changing the url like from /blog to /blog/{blog_id}.

I wanna know how to do it in a single page like have the same url as /blog and render the blog post content in the place where the posts were displayed and have a button to go back to the state of showing all the posts.
I'm new to reactjs . Any reference to such way of doing will be a lot helpful

Thank you

Comment: Don't use the router in that case. Use conditional renders and change the data that is being rendered. That will cause the page to automatically re-render and display new information.
https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#dialog) for this use case. but im not sure whether it is a good practise.